# Does Tkinter have a fixed or repeating update loop that I can use?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI running in the main thread with a second thread constantly taking input from a shared Queue.  Multiple background threads are doing different processes and the second thread takes all of their output and updates the GUI.  So far, no problems have come about, but there are countless warnings Tkinter is not thread safe.

With that being the case, I can copy all of this code into another constant loop, but I can't find out where I could put it so it's also in the main thread and does not lock up the GUI.  What is the right way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Tk and tkinter are more thread safe than some people claim.  My experiments and issues on the tracker show that updating widgets in threads works much better on 3.x than with 2.x.  That said, periodically reading a Queue to update widgets can probably be done more efficiently in an properly timed root.after function than in a separate thread as calling a function is faster than a thread switch.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, could you elaborate a bit?  I think I understand the after function after looking at the documentation, but the function populating the queue in a separate thread is doing so very quickly.  So if I only read the queue every 50 or 100 ms, then I'd have to skip to the most recent entry of the queue for the widget to display accurately.  Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Searching SO for "[tkinter] root.after" will give you lots of example answers.  ... If values are generated only for display, then the function should be slowed (by sleeping between values).  For readability, 1 change per second is about the limit.  For emptying a queue, see the queue for the 'I am empty' signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter has an event loop that runs. You can leverage that by writing a function that continuously adds itself to the event queue periodically.

The solution looks roughly like this:

```
def some_func():

    <do your work here>

    # call this function again in 1 second
    root.after(1000, some_func)
```

Once you call it once, it will continue to be called once a second. In production code you'll need to add a bit of bulletproofing, such as checking a flag that gets set when the app is shutting down.

This isn't exactly recursion, so you don't have to worry about running out of stack space since all this does is adds a new job in the event queue to run no sooner than one second after it was placed in the queue.

Comment: So I tried running it with 0 and the program never launches.  If I run it with 1, it works, but I was hoping it was something that just gets updated every time Tkinter is going through it's loop which should be a lot per second.   My only comparison to what I want is game programming with unity, there's a function called Update() thats provided and it runs over and over and over again as long as the game is running.

Comment: @user3000724: using zero starves the system. It's so busy running your code that it doesn't have a chance to service normal events. From a practical standpoint, you shouldn't run it much faster than every 100ms or so, or your UI will appear to lag. There's a single event queue that gets processed by `mainloop` so you need to be mindful of that. Do you really need your function to run more than 1000 times per second?

Comment: If one saves the id returned by root.after (`global after_id; after_id = root.after(...)`), then one can call `root.after_cancel(after_id)` in the shutdown function.  Seems cleaner to me.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I'm using paramiko for a large sftp transfer so I'm using a callback function.  The function gets called very frequently (I have no idea how to estimate it if its 10 or 1000 times a second) where it just prints to console the % completed.  I now have it pushing the int value to a Queue in a background thread and in the main gui thread It's setup to constantly read form the queue and use that int value to update a ttk.Progressbar.  I'm not sure if there's a better system for it.  Like I said, it works now, but if there's a cleaner way to do it, I want to learn it.

Comment: @user3000724: if all you're doing is updating a progress bar, once a second is plenty fast enough. Do you really think a user cares about the difference between 20 seconds remaining and 20.01 second remaining?

Comment: I agree with that, the problem is that I'm pushing data to a queue very quickly (a callback function), and if I only update every second, I think I would just have to flush the queue and get the most recent entry.  Is there a trick for this?