# Limiting the gui update in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Tkinter:

I want to limit how fast the gui updates itself when the user is changing the size of the window.

My plan was to have the application update like every 0.5 sec after "<Configure>", is called, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
def wait_function():
   root.wait()#i don't know what to do here.


root = tk.Tk()
root.bind("<Configure>", wait_function)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `root.after(...)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Tkinter have a fixed or repeating update loop that I can use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949829/does-tkinter-have-a-fixed-or-repeating-update-loop-that-i-can-use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell: write a function to do whatever work needs to be done. Whenever you receive the `<Configure>` event, schedule the function using `after`. Before doing so, remove any previously called invocation.

**Note**: It's important to realize that the root window is unique. When you bind any event specifically to the root window, that binding will be triggered by every widget in the root window. Therefore, if you want the bound function to only be called when the `<Configure>` event has been triggered for the root window, you need to do a test inside the function to check that `event.widget` represents the root window.

To keep the example short, this example uses global variables. Normally I would recommend using a class for this type of thing, so I don't recommend this coding style in a real program.

The code has a variable named `count` which is initialized to zero, and then is updated each time the event is triggered. When the program starts up, the label will be blank until 500ms after the initial `<Configure>` event. After that, you can manually resize the window but the function will only be called once you've stopped resizing for at least half a second. You'll see that reflected in the number in the label being increased.

```
import tkinter as tk

def after_configure():
    global count
    count += 1
    label.configure(text=f"updated - {count}")

def schedule_work(event):
    global after_id
    if event.widget == root:
        if after_id:
            root.after_cancel(after_id)
        after_id = root.after(500, after_configure)

count = 0
after_id = None
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="", width=20)
label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.bind("<Configure>", schedule_work)

root.mainloop()
```